# Sort Javascript Object by key in an Array with non indexed array key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

The problem I face is that my array is not indexed by 0,1,2,3 etc.  Its indexes are an id 0654, 3423, 7543 etc...  so for example:

```
var obj = {};
obj["0654"] = { "Name" : "Tony" };
obj["3423"] = { "Name" : "Fred" };
obj["7543"] = { "Name" : "Dave" };
```

I am looking for a way to sort these by the Name key. But I keep getting an not a function error.  Not too sure what I am doing wrong.  I am using this code to sort it:

```
Array.prototype.sortByProp = function(p){
    return this.sort(function(a,b){
        return (a[p].toLowerCase() > b[p].toLowerCase()) ? 1 : (a[p].toLowerCase() < b[p].toLowerCase()) ? -1 : 0;
    });
}
```

Doing this:

```
obj.sortByProp("Name");
```

Any guidance or the best way to approach this would be greatly appreciated... If this is a duplicate from another post, my apologies please point me in the right direction because I searched for this scenario all over and could not find the solution? Also, if you could tell me why this doesn't work too I can then understand objects a little better.

Comment: Your obj is not an array

Comment: Objects don't have a sort order...

Comment: you want them sorted into a new array with index 0 being dave? etc..?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript) pretty much covers what you were looking for

Comment: you can't re-order numeric object properties, only alpha keys will stay custom ordered (in insertion order)

Comment: I see, this is great info.  I definitely overlooked this.  Now that I am not trying to sort an array but objects of an object. I need to write some sort of function to do it. But I would like to rearrange the original object.  How do you convert it to an array then back in a function?

Answer (score 0):

[UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) is your best friend!

```
_.sortBy(obj, 'Name');
```

[Try it yourself.](http://jsfiddle.net/ho4aht5s/)

Comment: This looks real good and I didi try this method but it won't work in my setup?  Not too sure why. I didn't see DanDavis's comment but I do want to affect the original object.